# Python package for conversion of binary_liitle_endian to ascii for a ply format file?

Tags: ascii, binary-data, ply-file-format

I am looking to convert a little endian binary TO ASCII  for a ply file. I am looking for a package in python to do the same.

This can be easily done using cloud compare software but I am looking for a python package. I was trying uu.decode but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you mean that you have ASCII text in a byte string? Can you post an example of this byte string?

Comment: No I have a ply file in binary and want to convert it to ASCII

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually the author of exactly such a package: https://github.com/dranjan/python-plyfile

It should be as simple as reading in the PLY file and setting the `text` attribute:

```py
data = plyfile.PlyData.read('somefile.ply')
data.text = True
data.write('somefile-txt.ply')
```

Comment: Hi @Darsh Ranjan, I want to convert PLY files from ASCII to binary files. Can you please let me know what to do? Thanks

Comment: @Sher Sorry, I didn't see your question. You can set data.text to False and optionally data.byte_order to either '<' or '>'. One of the examples in this section illustrates that: https://python-plyfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#instance-mutability